# execute a jquery ajax code withot open a web page that execute it

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, laravel

i make a project with laravel 6
and i have database table name is buildings 
id - wood - clay - iron - crop - created_at - updated_at
1 - 25 - 54 - 57 - 63 - null - null 
so i make jquery ajax code to increment every column by 1 as test

game.js

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

setInterval(function(){ 
    var dataString    = 'id=1';
    $.ajaxSetup({ headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')} });
    $.ajax({
    type: "post", 
    url: "{{ route('upgradeBuildings') }}",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    beforeSend: function(){},
    success: function(data){
        $('.x').html(data);
    },
    error: function(err){console.log(err);}
    });
}, 1000);

});
```

LogsController

```html
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use App\Logs;
use App\Buildings;

class LogsController extends Controller
{

    public function upgradeBuildings(Request $request)
    {
        $id = $request->id;
        $updatecount = Buildings::increment("wood", "1");
        $buildings = Buildings::get()->first();
        $wood = $buildings->wood;
        return Response($wood);
    }

    public function village()
    {
        $buildings = Buildings::get();
        $users = DB::table('users')->get();
        $settings = DB::table('settings')->get()->first();
        return view('game.village', compact('buildings', 'settings', 'users')); 
    }
 
}
```

but these code is working when i opened page name village that's has game.js on it

i want this code working without i open this page

Answer (score 1):

You can create an `Artisan` command and run a `Task Scheduling`
The trick part is to run the function every second.

A workaround can be used:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class upgradeBuilding extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'buildings:upgrade';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'run every seconds';


    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     * 
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $count = 0;
        while ($count < 59) {
            $startTime =  Carbon::now();

            // Your logic here

            $endTime = Carbon::now();
            $totalDuration = $endTime->diffInSeconds($startTime);
            if($totalDuration > 0) {
                $count +=  $totalDuration;
            }
            else {
                $count++;
            }
            sleep(1);
        }

    }
}
```

then you schedule the command every minute:

```
$schedule->command('buildings:upgrade')->everyMinute();
```

Comment: can you teach me how to create a command and a schedule more explanation please

Comment: @Progromatic, the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/artisan#writing-commands) is very complete and extensive, you'll have your command set up in no time 

Answer (score 0):

This can be made using curl. Example:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://yourhost.example/route/' --header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN:token' --data-raw 'yourdatahere'
```

PS: remember to change the url, token value and data to the actual values you want to test

Comment: you can indeed run this curl as part of a CRON job, but wouldn't it be better to us the Laravel Schedulder instead?

Comment: Of course. But OP never mentioned that it would run every minute/hour/day/etc... This is just an example of one in N ways to achieve it.

Comment: Very true, I just assumed based on the setInterval 1000. Anyway OP would have many options to choose from now 

Comment: i want to know how to use curl first so can you show me how to made this request by curl and how i can install curl and add this command to it.

Comment: @Progromatic here is a guide on how to install it in windows: https://develop.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001068567-Installing-and-using-cURL
If you are using another OS, there is plenty of guides on the internet. Just have a 2 minutes search. Have fun

Comment: thank you CarlosCarucce you helped me installing curl the second stage is to execute ajax post request